# notifyDataSetChanged not working with RecyclerView + Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to refresh my RecyclerView attached data after reading data from the firebase database. `notifyDataSetChanged()` does not seem to work.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // use a linear layout manager
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new StationListAdapter(stations);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference stationsRef = database.getReference("stations");
    stationsRef.equalTo("Berlin").orderByChild("city").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            stations = (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + stations.toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

No items are shown in the list, but logging says there are items available. When adding items to `stations` **before** passing them to my adapter, they are displayed correctly:

```
HashMap<String, String> works = new HashMap<String, String>();
works.put("name", "berlin");
stations.add(works);
adapter = new StationListAdapter(stations);
```

I also tried to run `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the UIThread, same result. I don't want to use https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android. Any way to fix this? I have used RecyclerView several times and `notifyDataSetChanged()` worked fine everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this line:

```
stations = (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

It should have been:

```
stations.addAll((ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) dataSnapshot.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

You didnot updated the stations in the adapter class, just write a function in the adapter which sets the value of stations and then before notifydataset change call that function to set the stations, somewhat like

```
public void setStations(<Map<String, String>> stations){
this.stations=stations
}
```

this would work

Comment: stations are referenced in the Adapter, so it should work without refreshing them manually.

Comment: The data is which fuels your view, you need to change the data in the adapter which needs to be told every time you update the data and then the notifydatasetchange would work